# And I click on a menu item and it leads me to nowhere

Tags: menus

On my WP LP I have a menu where if you click on an item you would have been scrolled to a relevant place on the LP, on this one page, but if I'm on another page and I click on a menu it leads me to nowhere, it just stands still and does nothing because now after domain goes slash and the slug of the page and only here goes my #ID - http://vidguard.ru/videonablyudenie-dlya-dachi#etapii, if I click item Этапы. So I need when I click it the slug after domain disappears and be like http://vidguard.ru/#etapii. How to achieve it?

Comment: In your menu use full url as `<a href="http://vidguard.ru/#etapii">` instead of  `<a href="#etapii">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each menu item set the URL to `/#yourid` instead of `#yourid`. That way it points to the ID on the homepage, not on the current page/post/cpt.

Comment: Thanks, it works only now the menu items changed color but I'll fix it I hope. Thanks!